# Transactional update policy for multiple tables with the same source table

Tags: azure-data-explorer

Let's say I have two tables on which I define two different update policies but with the same source table. Both the update policies are transactional. So basically the two update policies look like this:-

```
.alter table Target1 policy update @'[{"IsEnabled": true, "Source": "MySource", "Query": "UpdatePolicy1_MySource()", "IsTransactional": true, "PropagateIngestionProperties": false}]'

.alter table Target2 policy update @'[{"IsEnabled": true, "Source": "MySource", "Query": "UpdatePolicy2_MySource()", "IsTransactional": true, "PropagateIngestionProperties": false}]'
```

Now since both of the update policies are transactional, as per the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/kusto/management/updatepolicy)

> If transactional and the update policy fails, the source table is not
> updated

So what will happen in my case where only one of the update policy fails? Source table for both the update policies is the same in my case , does it mean that all the update policies for a given source table have to succeed before source table is updated ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, if the update policies are transactional, all have to succeed for commit to take place. If any update policy fails, there will be no ingestion to any of the tables.